# Resource recommendation on Macroscopic electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations

I would like to know about all books, papers, articles, heck at this point even rock engravings, to thoroughly understand the process of averaging microscopic equations to arrive at macroscopic equations, and the nitty gritties of macroscopic electromagnetism; especially when it comes to deriving macroscopic formulae from microscopic formulae.

I want to know where, which procedure applies, the boundary cases, all of that.

More importantly, I need books that speak about electrostatic energy in terms of macroscopic variables in great detail, not just books that speak about what happens superficially instead of what is happening when one writes the equations (eg, Griffiths, jackson, in the chapter on energy of dielectrics) for I have read many a textbook on this, and they hardly cover any of the physically logical issues I face when it comes to macroscopic energy description. I have read bits and pieces of FNH robinson, and to me, it seems more like a summarisation of the entire thing to readers who already know the entire thing. And to add to that he entirely avoids the questions that I have with the logical deductions regarding macroscopic electrostatic energy.

Note: This is not a highly specific request on the topic of energy, but rather, a request on a general coverage of the entire procedure, *AND* a solid physical coverage of energy.

I have asked a few questions on SE, with quite unsatisfactory answers, or none at all, on some of these topics, and it is in general clear to me I have some deep misunderstandings on this process.

I'm a guy who doesn't understand the math behind spatial ensemble averages, for I haven't taken a statistics course, nor do I understand the mathematics of truncation procedure, again, for I don't know Fourier transforms. But I can for sure, intuitively see what's happening, say for example when you tell me a micro variable $ \chi(r) $ gets averaged using a smooth weighting function $ f(s) $ through the process $$\left< \chi(r) \right> = \iiint \chi(r-s) f(s) d^3s  $$

With this information, I hope I can get some recommendations to continue my self-study on the topic, for this is a major roadblock for me.

Comment: I suggest that you read Russakoff: A Derivation of the Macroscopic Maxwell Equations, see https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/38/10/1188/1041160/A-Derivation-of-the-Macroscopic-Maxwell-Equations?redirectedFrom=fulltext an excellent work.

Comment: In my view studying the FDTD method of EM simulation would help you find answers. It will present a mechanistic approach of how things happen by small changes over time. John B. Schneider has a free pdf book about it. Another book is Davidson Computational Electromagnetics (you can focus only on the FDTD chapters).